# PHP not running in VirtualHost on Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, plesk

I had to migrate from an old server `(Plesk 14; CentOS 5; Apache 2.2; PHP 5.3.5)` to a new one `(Plesk Onyx 17; CentOS 7.3; Apache 2.4; PHP 7)`

Everything works fine with the exception of the custom Virtual Hosts.

On the old server, in my `etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I had the following and it was working:

```
<VirtualHost XX.XX.XX.XX:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mycompany.com/httpdocs/myproject
 ServerName  myproject.com
 ServerAlias www.myproject.com

   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/mycompany.com/httpdocs/myproject>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
          php_admin_flag engine on
          php_admin_flag safe_mode on
        </IfModule>

       <IfModule mod_php5.c>
          php_admin_flag safe_mode off
          php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/tmp"
          php_admin_value session.save_path "/tmp"
       </IfModule>

       php_admin_flag engine on
       AddHandler php5-script .php

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I didn't have the `php_admin_flag engine on` and the `AddHandler` it would just download the php file as text.

On the new server I tried the exact same  and it just downloads the php file.

I also tried adding the following in `<Directory>` with no success:

```
LoadModule php5_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#Error:  Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.

php_admin_flag engine on
# Invalid command 'php_admin_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

AddType text/html .php 
#I used this to make sure AddType works. It does - PHP displayed as HTML

AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
#Downloads the file as text

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
#Downloads the file as text

AddType php5-script  .php
#Shows php as plain text
```

Something worth mentioning is that on this Plesk there are multiple PHP versions. When I do `php -v` I get `PHP 5.3.5 (cli)` but when I use `phpinfo()` in a page I get "PHP Version 7.0.18".

My guess is that it has something to do with that.

On the Admin panel in Plesk it says `run PHP 7 as FPS Application`

[image: plesk-php-fpm]

Here's a snapshot of the `phpinfo()` https://pste.eu/p/BGpI.html

Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi Miro,**

did you consider to SWITCH from MPM-EVENT to MPM-PREFORK, in order to be able to USE the libapache2 - PHP - module ?

```
LoadModule php5_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#Error:  Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
```

**=> HOME > Tools & Settings > Apache Web Server > ( option ) MPM mode**

Comment: Changed the MPM to `Prefork` it works great now with this:

`LoadModule php5_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/libphp5.so`
|
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`

Thank you!

Comment: The downside to this is that it's running php5 now. Any idea how to loadModule for php7?

Comment: "Any idea how to loadModule for php7" - Sure... just upgrade your vendor PHP - version to 7.0 or even 7.1. Example for CentOS 7.3: => yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php71 install php-pecl-apcu php-cli php-pear php-pdo php-mysqlnd php-pgsql php-pecl-mongodb php-pecl-memcache php-pecl-memcached php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml

Comment: Hmm. What i meant was how to use the existing php 7 that comes with plesk? For example [this](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/elevation/centralamerica/ver.php) and [this](http://www.nuestrapatrianuestrofuturo.com/ver.php) open the same file on server but one is routed through VirtualHost with libphp5.so. Any idea how to load the existing php 7?

Comment: Miro... you might misunderstand something here: The additional Plesk PHP versions don't have an libapache2 - PHP - module for your apache - webserver and you can only use ONE of these modules for your installed apache - webserver on your server. ;-)

Comment: You're right. I don't get why the default domain works with php 7 but the virtual host doesn't parse it. Maybe I need to use mod_fastcgi or something?